# Does Canonical Periodically Update a Given AMI?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-ami

I've looked and looked, but I cannot find the answer to this question.

Given a specific AMI ID (for example, an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS AMI, published by Canonical itself), will Canonical periodically update that specific AMI ID, with new security updates? Or do they just publish a brand new AMI, and never update an existing AMI ID?

The reason I ask is for usage with something like Concourse CI, which can be set to trigger pipelines to run when an AMI is changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, AMIs are immutable. They do publish updated AMIs periodically, though.